# icd9 regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I cannot find a definitive guide to icd9 code formats.

Can anyone explain the format - especially the use of trailing and leading zeros?

A C# regex for icd9 and icd10 codes would also be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for fully qualified codes, or are incomplete codes also allowed in your application?

Comment: Just a note: using regex for ICD only validates it is in the correct pattern.  It does not ensure that the code exists! Consult CMS code lists for all possible [ICD9](https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/ICD9ProviderDiagnosticCodes/codes.html) and [ICD10](https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/ICD10/2016-ICD-10-CM-and-GEMs.html) codes.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and found what I believe to be a more complete answer. Thought I'd help anyone else coming in the future.

**ICD-9 Regex**

The ICD 9 format has a bunch of ways it can be formatted. It can begin with V, E, or a number.

- If it begins with V, then it has 2 numbers, a decimal, then up to
  two numbers

  - Examples: `V10.12` and `V12`
- If it begins when E, then it has 3 numbers, the decimal place, then up to two numbers

  - Examples: `E000.0` and `E002`
- If it begins with a number, then it is up to 3 numbers, a decimal, then up to two numbers

  - Examples: `730.12` and `730`

A good regex that checks all these rules is (Credit goes to [sascomunitt](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Validate_the_format_of_ICD-9_codes))

```
^(V\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?|\d{3}(\.\d{1,2})?|E\d{3}(\.\d)?)$
```

**ICD-10 Regex**

According to [www.cms.gov](https://www.cms.gov/ICD10/Downloads/032310_ICD10_Slides.pdf) ICD-10 has the following rules:

- 3-7 Characters
- Character 1 is alpha (cannot be U)
- Character 2 is numeric
- Characters 3-7 are alphanumeric
- After 3 characters you use a decimal
- Use of dummy placeholder "x" (This is the only one I am not accounting for in my regex...)
- Alpha characters are not case sensitive

Here is the regex I came up with:

```
^[A-TV-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9](\.[A-Z0-9]{1,4})?$
```

**Note** These regexes are for javascript and may need tweaked for C# (I'm too lazy to test it right now)

Comment: Thanks! this is a better answer than the accepted one since it includes E Codes and V Codes.  Only annoying thing is this us government form I'm writing a program for requires the '.' after the first three numbers, so lame!

Comment: Technically, the character "U" is valid. It's been reserved for future use by the WHO, but is a valid character. [Reference](http://www.cihi.ca/CIHI-ext-portal/internet/en/document/standards+and+data+submission/standards/classification+and+coding/codingclass_icd10struct)

Comment: according to the link you have for ICD-9 the correct regex is `^([V\d]\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?|E\d{3}(\.\d)?|\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?)$` because in the last section he states `    Note that ICD-9 *procedure* codes are different yet again--these move the decimal *up* a place.`

Comment: Works ok for most; but some icd 9 begining with V match both regexes.Examples :V01, V01.0, V01.1, V01.2, V01.3

Comment: @chohi That is because they are valid both as ICD-9 and as ICD-10 codes.

Comment: are you saying the format is valid or the values themselves are valid? they seem different here https://www.cms.gov/medicare-coverage-database/staticpages/icd-10-code-lookup.aspx?KeyWord=V01&bc=AAAAAAAAAAACAA%3d%3d& and here https://www.cms.gov/medicare-coverage-database/staticpages/icd-9-code-lookup.aspx?KeyWord=v01&bc=AAAAAAAAAAAEAA%3d%3d&

Comment: While not billable, it is a valid code. Try downloading the entire CMS ICD-10 codes file and it will include V01.1 with the description "Pedestrian injured in collision with pedal cycle in traffic accident". The link you provided only includes billable codes.

Comment: Doesn't ICD9 have 3-5 characters (without the decimal place)? Wouldn't that make the codes that begin with E "If it begins when E, then it has 3 numbers, the decimal place, then up to 1 number" instead of  "then up to 2 numbers"? The regular expression works for E123.4 but not E123.45 anyway.

Comment: For ICD9/10 duplicate codes, see: http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Duplicate_Codes

Answer (score 10):

An ICD-9 code looks like this:

- two/three-digit numeric code (may have leading zeroes to pad to three digits)
- an optional dot
- if that dot is present, there will be one or two following digits, depending on the preceding three digits. Which digits are allowed specifically is very variable.
- Some codes are prefixed by an `E` or `V`.

An ICD-10 code looks like this:

- an uppercase ASCII letter (A-Z)
- two digits
- an optional dot
- if that dot is present, there will be one or two following digits. Again, it's highly variable which ICD codes allow for which digits after the dot.
- Sometimes, you'll find an asterisk, a plus sign (at least in ASCII texts), or an exclamation point after a code. They are used in certain combination codes.

So, in essence, you could use regex to find ICD codes in a text, but you won't be able to validate them.

A C# regex for ICD-9 codes could look like this: `@"\b[EV]?\d{2,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b"`.

For an ICD-10 code: `@"\b[A-Z]\d{2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?\b[*+!]?"`

Comment: What are the rules for trailing zeroes?  I thought I've seen 2 digit codes without the leading zero.

Comment: Tim is correct, there are codes with only 2 digits prior to the dot, such as 00.12 and 99.75.  These are just 2 examples.  There are many more.

Comment: See Section 1-B-3 for more details on coding format: http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/icd/icd9cm_guidelines_2011.pdf

That document states that ICD-9 _diagnosis_ codes should be 3, 4, or 5 characters long. This section actually says 'digits' not 'characters' but this is obviously incorrect as one of the subsequent sections refers to V and E codes as @lecrank mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to ICD-9 diagnosis codes? Then see this thread: [ICD-9 Code List in XML, CSV, or Database format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653811/icd-9-code-list-in-xml-csv-or-database-format).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of ICD 9 codes: Diagnosis Codes & Procedure Codes

for the Diagnosis Codes Gordon Tucker has the correct answer:

```
^(V\d{2}(\.\d{1,2})?|\d{3}(\.\d{1,2})?|E\d{3}(\.\d)?)$
```

ICD-9-CM procedure codes are 2 numbers, a decimal, then up to two numbers (to be a complete code 2 numbers are required)

A regex for these codes would be:

```
^\d{2}.\d{1,2}$
```

[ICD-9-CM Procedure Codes](http://www.icd9data.com/2012/Volume3/default.htm)
[2012 ICD-9-CM Diagnosis Codes](http://www.icd9data.com/2012/Volume1/default.htm)